# Is this a valid way to calculate SNR?

Tags: signal-detection, snr, signal-power

If I calculate

1.) the average power of a signal, $P_s$, in terms of the average energy of the signal, $E_s$ and take it as a constant over a given period of time, $T_s$, as $P_s=E_s/T_s$ where $E_s$ has units Joules and $T_s$ has units of time; and then

2.) calculate noise power, $P_n$, as the the product of the average noise energy, $N_e$, and the noise bandwidth over a given frequency range (determined by the receiver which cannot be changed), $B_n$, that is $P_n=N_eB_n$ where the noise energy has units of Joules and noise bandwidth has units of "per time"; and then

3.) form the ratio $P_s/P_n$;

then can I say this is a valid $\textit{snr}$ calculation?  If not, then what are the specific problems with this approach?

Comment: $P_s/P_n$ seems to be the *only* valid way to calculate SNR; so, where is your doubt arising from?

Comment: I'm thinking the use of average signal energy and average noise energy would produce an $\textit{snr}$ with questionable accuracy.  My other concern is that I have not come across a similar calculation in text books (for example, Peebles or Papoulis).

Comment: well, your noise is stationary, and your signal power seems to be to, so I don't see the problem with working with the average here?

Comment: OK, yes, it seems to me that the assumption of stationary processes are the key to understanding the conditions under which those calculations would be valid.  Thanks very much.